# X11 forwarding from Linux cluster to windows 10 personal computer via SSH

Tags: x11

Our cluster runs Linux, and I can successfully ssh login to it using my windows 10 PC. 
However, when I'm trying to use X11 forwarding I always get the error:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:0.0
Could not connect to any X display
```

I've tried everything: using Xterminal, PuTTY, Ubuntu (from the windows 10 store), MobaXterm - and nothing works.
I've tried the export display command, and when I'm logging in I'm using -X (also tried -Y).
I read online but couldn't find anything to work.
Also, my colleague has a personal Macbook with the same user properties, and she managed to do X11 using XQuartz.

Any ideas what can I try?

Comment: Did you try:

export DISPLAY=<name of your Windows host pc>:0.0

?

Comment: Do you somehwere (e.g. in the shell login script) set `DISPLAY`? Because with `ssh`, it should be `localhost:10` or above, and not `localhost:0.0`.

Comment: MobaXterm and Xming should give you some info about running displays. MobaXterm has a button for "X server" and I think Xming will tell you the display if you hover over the tray icon. What X server(s) do you have running?

Answer (score 1):

When using SSH X11 forwarding, the display number should be 10.0 or above normally.

If the error message really says `localhost:0.0` it suggests there could be some environment setting on the cluster that is overriding the `DISPLAY` variable. **Don't do that**: the `sshd` on the remote end will set the `DISPLAY` variable to the correct value automatically as part of your session initialization when X11 forwarding has been requested and accepted. You cannot know the right value in advance, as it will vary based on how many other X11-forwarding SSH connections to the cluster have already been established when you make your connection.

**Note:** Setting `export DISPLAY=<name of your Windows host pc>:0.0` at the cluster would cause any applications to attempt an insecure, unencrypted X11 connection directly from the application to the X11 server on your Windows host. **This is not recommended** and might (or rather should!) be blocked by firewalls/NAT at either end.